# Java Method Reference (pass method as parameter)

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I want to pass method as a parameter in a method like

callMethod(someArg, **methodToPass**)

And in the definition of callMethod,  I want to call this fn ie. MethodToPass i.e in another java file and the arguments for fn MethodToPass are being initialized in this callMethod only.

Please tell me how can I do that??

Comment: What is your question? How to specify the method in caller? Or how to define `callMethod`?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta  I want to pass only reference of "methodToPass" in "callMethod" and its arguments i'm calculating inside callMethod definition and after that I want to call this method that I passed as a Parameter with the arguments I calculated in "callMethod" fn

Comment: You may want to read on this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern and also checkout java.util.function javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the signature of your "methodToPass".

For example, if your method accepts a single argument and has a return type, you can use `Function<X,Y>`:

```
public static <X,Y> Y callMethod (X arg, Function<X,Y> func) {
    return func.apply(arg);
}
```

and call it with:

```
Integer result = callMethod ("abc", String::length);
```

If your method has a signature that doesn't match predefined functional interfaces, you can create a custom interface.

Either generic:

```
public interface MyFunc<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>
{
    public void apply (T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4, T5 t5);
}
```

or not:

```
public interface MyFunc
{
    public void apply (Type1 t1, Type2 t2, Type3 t3, Type4 t4, Type5 t5);
}
```

where TypeN represent actual classes.

Now, `callMethod` becomes (in the non-generic version):

```
public static void callMethod (MyFunc method) {
    Type1 a1 = ...
    Type2 a2 = ...
    Type3 a3 = ...
    Type4 a4 = ...
    Type5 a5 = ...
    method.apply(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5);
}
```

And you call it with:

```
callMethod (SomeClass::methodToPass);
```

Where `methodToPass` is defined as:

```
static void methodToPass (Type1 t1, Type2 t2, Type3 t3, Type4 t4, Type5 t5) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: My signature of "methodToPass" has return type void and it accepts 5 arguments of different types and I want to pass only its reference in "callMethod" and its arguments  i'm calculating inside callMethod definition and after that I want to call this method that I passed as a Parameter with the arguments I calculated in "callMethod" fn

Comment: Ok, I'll try this solution. I'm able to understand it and will update you about it. Thanku

Comment: Useful to add that `SomeClass` can also be an instance if you want to call a non-static method and it can also be `this` if you want to reference the current instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a `@FunctionalInterface` containing the method (although chances are the JDK already provides one).

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MethodToPass {
    void methodToCall(int someArg);
}
```

Then, you can pass the method as a reference:

```
class YourClass {
    // note same signature as the inferface method
    public void methodToPass(iont arg) { 
        System.out.println("called with " + arg);
    }
}

class OtherClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        YourClass c = new YourClass();
        callMethod(c::methodToPass);
    }
    public void callMethod(MethodToPass method) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            method.methodToCall(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, the most common signatures already exist in the JDK - in this case, it's a `Consumer<Integer>`.

Comment: Yes, I get it what you are saying but in my case I'm calculating the value of the arguments to pass in MethodToPass() inside callMethod(). So, I can't do like callMethod(3, c::methodToPass); because for me I'm calculating this value let "3" inside callMethod and want to call methodToPass( with "calculatedValue" as parameter)

Comment: @Shifali It's not entirely clear to me what exactly you're trying to do. I adjusted the code to "calculate the values" in `callmethod`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this solution too. I'm able to understand it and will update you about it. Thanku

Comment: @Shifali Good to know :) Feel free to set as answered.